# fonts don't load on webkit.net browser in windows application

Tags: c#

I have developed one windows application with webkit.net control by using its dll.
In which when we open any webpage of local folder it doesn't show fonts. 
(i.e. webkit .net has font issues, different fonts are not loaded in its browser.)

What should I do?
Is there a property we have to set over there for this control?